# Javascript / Jquery - Multiple on Change (function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am kinda new to Jquery / JS and after a little help. I realise there hopefully is a much better way to do this, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am building a form that can calculate a total. That is:

'Cost' x '(1 + percent(%))' = 'total cost'

I have it working nicely, though I want to make it so that if I change either the '**percent**' field, or the '**cost**' field then the **total amount** updates. At the moment only if you update the '**cost**' will the **total update**.

Hope that makes sense. Code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#cost").change(function() { 
var findprofit = parseFloat($("#cost").val());
var profit = (findprofit*.01)
var margin = parseFloat($("#percentage").val());
var total = profit*margin;
$(".profit_1_1").html(total);
var totalprofit = (total + findprofit);
$("#total").val(totalprofit);
});

<input type="text" name="cost" id="cost"  />
<input type="text" name="percentage" id="cost" percentage />
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly />
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$("#cost, #percent").change(function() { 
    ...
});
```

Should do the trick.

Edit: You'll need to give your percent input an id of "percent". Two elements may not have the same ID.

```
<input type="text" name="cost" id="cost"  />
<input type="text" name="percentage" id="percent" percentage />
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly />
```

Also I'm not sure what that "percentage" is at the end of the input. Percentage isn't a valid attribute.

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew it was something fairly straight forward. Really appreciated!